# How to install monitor drivers manually?

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, display

I'm running Windows 7 64bits, and I need to install Dell 2407wfp drivers. The only issue is, the drivers from the website does not execute right after I download them, like they are supposed to.

If I try to manually install them (update driver in the control panel) I get a message saying that I already have the best drivers, and the the installation ends there.

Any ideas what could I do?, I get a couple of files an a .inf files I think it's used for this purpose. But no idea how to force Windows to accept them.

Comment: How do you know the drivers aren't installed? Have you tried rolling back the existing drivers and then manually update? Also, are you using the Vista drivers? Is your Windows 7 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Because it says "PnP generic monitor". And because I never installed them before, it is a clean Windows install. I'm using the latest drivers Dell offers for my monitor, which are for XP and Vista.

Comment: Would it be a solution if you run those drivers in compatible mode?

Comment: Plug-n-play drivers are native to Windows 7, so they were there when you installed Windows. You didn't answer my last question about your computer. Since the drivers are 32-bit only, if your system is 64-bit they may not be compatible at all.

Comment: I never said the drivers were 64 bits only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First download and unzip the Dell monitor driver to your local system if you haven't already. Note the directory because you will have to reference it later. Default should be C:\Dell\Drivers\R151591.
2. Click Windows Start, right-click on "Computer" and then select "Properties".
3. Click the "Device Manager" link.
4. Expand the "Monitors" list, right-click on the "Plug and Play Monitor" and then select "Update Driver Software".
5. Click "Browse my computer for driver software".
6. Then click the "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer".
7. Click the "Have Disk..." button.
8. Click the "Browse..." button.
9. Browse to the folder where the Dell monitor drivers were unzipped to, default should be C:\Dell\Drivers\R151591.
10. Select the "2407WFPHC.INF" file and click the "Open" button.
11. Click "OK".
12. Select the "Dell 2407WFP-HC (Digital)" from the list and then click "Next".
13. Follow the steps to complete the install and then restart Windows.